# Unpack error while using sklearn columntransfromer

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I was trying to one hot encode a dataframe for some testing.

I tried using the regular `OneHotEncoder` from `sklearn` but It seemed to have some issues with `NaN` values (`NaN` values that were not present on columns I wanted to encode)

From what I searched, a solution was to use a column transformer, which could apply the encoding only to certain columns, something like the following

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([(OneHotEncoder(categories = categories_list),['col1','col2','col3'])])
```

In which `categories_list` is a list of all present categories.

The problem is that when I try to apply this transformer to my dataframe, I always get `not enough values to unpack` error.

Im transforming like this

`ct.fit_transform(df_train_xgboost)`

Any idea on what should I do?

EDIT:

Some example Data

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3 | price | has_something
1    blue   car    new    23781       NaN
2    green  truck  used   24512       1
3    red    van    new    44521       0
```

Some more code

```
categories_list = ['blue','green','red','car','truck','van','new','used']
df_train_xgboost = df_train
df_train_xgboost = df_train_xgboost.drop(columns_I_dont_want, axis=1)
df_train_xgboost = df_train_xgboost.fillna(value = {'col1': 0, 'col2': 0, 'col3': 0})

ct = ColumnTransformer([(OneHotEncoder(categories = categories_list),['col1','col2','col3'])])

print(df_train_xgboost.shape)
ct.fit_transform(df_train_xgboost)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First of all, the use of `ColumnTransformer` is **not** necessary.

1. To make your code work you need one more input argument i.e., the "name" of the transformer.

   Full example:

```
df
    col1   col2  col3
0   blue    car   new
1  green  truck  used
2    red    van   new

ct = ColumnTransformer([("onehot",OneHotEncoder(),[0,1,2])])

ct.fit_transform(df.values)
array([[1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

---

2. Now notice that you get the same output by only using `OneHotEncoder`:

```
o = OneHotEncoder()
o.fit_transform(df).toarray()

array([[1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, I tried using the second solution at the start, but having `NaNs` in my dataframe makes it so It does not work, thats why I tried going for the transformer.
First solution seems the best for my case, but I keep getting `argument must be string or number` at `fit_transform` stage

Comment: this error meas that your dataframe contains something that is not string or number. Do you want to include the NaNs?

Comment: Yes if its possible, mainly because NaNs are pretty spreaded out, so dropping rows that contain them is not an option.

Comment: then use `df.fillna(0)` to fill the NaNs with value 0 or something else